# Mapping an array of data to specific react components based on a type field in the data

Tags: reactjs, typescript

We are trying to map a Record with a specific set of keys and values to specific react components. The values can be arbitrary but all values must have a property `type` from a specific set of types.

We have gone a long way to structure our values in a way with which we can look up a value type by its `type` property. Our thinking was that if we can do that, we can use the `type` property, look up the value type and map that value type to a specific react component.

But it did not work.

I think I can explain the issue the best way by mixing code with explanatory comments, so I will go on  with a code block from here:

[You can find the entire code below as a TypeScript Playground here.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wChSB6AKitLirgBUALYAZznbggFco4AJihgo4ICAKQAbKcAB2AczoNlTZkjgKIKKXHVFOHGBDhoiwjaIBGKNhvGTdACjQ6pSAQQCSMJCHwAlHAwzMKmKHJwVhpIAB6%20cpKeAO7AIXAoAgJpwBByOqpCIlE88CA8bPCgYO4gSHLwIRo2bMBocD5%20cJjA0gIcTsmsaMzB6nBgOGBIsACeBDCz04EAdKoA6pZSbCbJEb6exnooAG6WYihg3JhjGovTRqHwyRqhZ8EmTcD8DtJsK2oNMBJKJMNAxlw9hxVEcQCgANZA57QeHdcEVD4XK73JAcCA3X7bTFffhsaZoYA9donFBQYD7NjKCjkCgUOAACRmGhex3eojQvBqGnxUVsdyWuNIOI6vhAjAlcAAvAsAIz4OAAHwWACZ1Vr8DAAMxkShsza884tewSaQENJ%20dUhMKhDig3pSTwGiXqoZtUZcEWdOUS0jyXxQTDoDRBgA8jDgcQS-Rlfnl0wAfHAAN50OB5nEALiYAG5SABfFlslhcSQ9OS4jIEZACqACGPpx1PLEcJBnKDzINpyyuuCI%20ZHCIpvAip2NBW2Rs0qQ8JCkOKQWDBBXN6ACADymCDHGVWbgAG0ANKcSKDiUAXSLsYvmbLpdNai46ik0347hgHAxRN6kOcYWjaRAkBbfdD1lDh5EbHE2BQTBuRQWYC3fdY0lGEJIQ0VxIiAxJbggqCDyPDJiLhRE4DYPgYnQUYx0MWiYGAGRKPfW9pkokCNCXFcWMnIjWjya4SPQKD5AUKc1lZOAAE1eHCOQ5AgeBMk8dT9FHJBZldYjZmUgi1PgCphSafgBNxNZ12gOceKPOME3iYCOB3VtyNgzNlUYN95OrODHg0MlIMpcDqlqeoRDYsSZ3GDzoKPAAaOAeTeO4VQAWiNDIODHNhkvfYhRjyIEODhMAwGkzFJ3tPArFKFykxqtI0uw25vm4ZJIkmCAwEZaUgwAWUuJUpzYGMczzfMVSLU9C1VfBizRCAi3wMEIHVOBX1zfNtXmrdpnWmBdRW0UoHWmwoHVXaZuCQ1DsWg1jXOmwAC8rpQd7btLMt038tkADkIGSW47DSrlBCQOscjyPEbiaCYIDYVorHcQRhFEWdIYtVKmnfIpREqKAeAweixjCdLTnKyiMigKA0PE%20r-kBOBzB2SIeTMVBfE4%20SRrGiJPDUsGMrp2lGfmEU0g4aygpI4FUEp558N4D0sXfJHuIbX0RlxgjunkTx4KRgADHEzaNvpiXGSTdxq2t5DhuR33i61HDS9QuY0cw%20Mx4phbgesPExKQIAgVEeCuPXRklpn6s4cAooaRl5NjsQbSkUgBTkSoA5QR9ZVGsAzzHQNi8uO8zzvcazz27MjqQE61VSzb1s27ayyK%206FolE7dVSi6vpunae5mvvjoWY0h4%20r6frHhvJ%20bnV8Fn2kR9u8e82Xlu19WjuI677fG%20e079%20Hghrq3pem4Hi-rs3xfe7v6eH%20%20%20eb7vFkaFUQKWN4PwcwGAk5CjqA0YQuQub6G5PYMagCC6YmAfAAU4AyqpyZJWOA5oeYWEotpGYpFdwq27IrWUTcjAmGQOgFBuBID1gwdKAAwnQ9BMAS7jVPGeeM8EdYPggjQlYAA1AAYkwqanBZRFz8CXbhtd-o7XIO%20f%20XAkaRT8NFSBcVEZPBzvDWhaCGHsMuEWFhhjoocJPLmGAc04BOFPInMsQRFSZhjGAdMDjZQrE2jtGMFB3Hj1OkWexkiuhOKVK49xni-ArGur4-x6ZAmPTsdEvA4SXFwDcR40JIBYnfXiQE8sWCQZgzcOJHG0ofFxKhJiaidxWAcGSCiIsCgkAaUiPVVK4dI7vjDCYWWTdeLszaXwSISN7athqsg0wrCjEGU8GAWwwUcmYjSMo8YStRA1JxkOAAymYYAYB4BsGYOrTwPBEgzEqEHHGQx6i41ae0lZ7tBmMGUbsmZPANYXMkFAa5xEKkwKEjMhmuJ6HZEUHAMx9Dopon4ICsIcIYAjAbGo2UpBMAXIwFAzQbSACiKcYDOSIsmHW6YnD1WkSAOM6YgjTRmrnfO0K2HjVQTChosj6orBxHeUs90iAwFGZk5lRicmKizPVMscAKAAyKe%20RqVR4ACAgA2UyaUUQAiRiK2FJl1JRA0H1H8Uh5iVWmAIVKjAPnKtVXq3s9R3x2C6EcaIMy5AnHkGgUO5ttUNCtjyR5AD6zlPGGythCMSKVXfEHXVZQxptSOGiroC5RCGtIEAA)

```js
import React from "react"

/**
 * This is our data modeling
 * 
 * The goal here is to create a base model (called "Item") that can be extended with additional
 * data but must implement the basic Item fields (which the property "type").
 * We also wanted to have a map of the types that we have to their models. The idea for this was 
 * to make it work for us to map types of models to their specific variants
 */

// Here we have a couple of base types
type ItemType = "t1" | "t2" | "t3"

// We have a base model "item" that has a field "type" which is of ItemType
interface Item<T extends ItemType> {
    type: T;
}

// This defines a "Record<>" that maps every ItemType as a key to an Item of that type as a value
export type RecordOfItems = { [K in ItemType]: Item<K> };

// This helper lets us extend the basic RecordOfItems in a typesafe way:
// With this we can extend the RecordOfItems and make sure each key is still an
// ItemType and the value is an extension of the according Item.
// You cannot add other keys and you cannot use other values.
export type Items<T extends RecordOfItems> = T;

// This is the specific implementation of the RecordOfItems, we have t1-t3 as keys,
// each one is mapping to an item but extending it with their own props
type ItemMap = Items<{
    t1: { type: "t1"; foo: "foo"  };
    t2: { type: "t2";  bar: "bar" };
    t3: { type: "t3";  baz: "baz" };
}>;

// Now these were definitions of the possible data that we have, the
// data structure that we have is an array of items. The reason we create an
// ItemMap and now have an array of its values is the idea that we could map
// the ItemTypes which we can find in the `type` field to the according definition
// of the model when we read the data and need to look up which array item implements
// which model
const data: ItemMap[keyof ItemMap][] = [
    { type: "t1", foo: "foo"  },
    { type: "t2",  bar: "bar" },
    { type: "t3",  baz: "baz" },
    { type: "t2",  bar: "bar" },
    { type: "t1", foo: "foo"  },
    { type: "t2",  bar: "bar" },
    { type: "t2",  bar: "bar" },
    { type: "t3",  baz: "baz" },
]

/**
 * This is our react implementation where we map our data to react components
 */

// We create another Record that maps the item types to React components
type ComponentMap = { [T in ItemType]: React.VFC<{ item: ItemMap[T] }> }


// This is the implementation of that
const componentMap: ComponentMap = {
  t1: ({ item }) => <p>{ item.foo }</p>,
  t2: ({ item }) => <p>{ item.bar }</p>,
  t3: ({ item }) => <p>{ item.baz }</p>,
}

// Now all of that type foo bar was to make this work: get an item, look
// into its type and return the according react components and pass the item to it
// The idea was that TypeScript should understand that when we get an item of the type T
// TS could understand that there is a corresponding Component for that that matches the item
function getElement<T extends ItemType>(item: Item<T>) {
    const Component = componentMap[item.type];
    return <Component item={item} />;
}

// but it does not work. the Component cannot be properly mapped, TS does not even
// seem to be convinced the `Component` we get is one of the components of the map
// and cannot map it to the item as a prop
```

Answer (score 1):

It's took me a bit )

First of all, `item: Item<T>` can't be used as a prop for Component, because it has only `type` props. `Item` type does not contain `foo`/`bar`/`baz`

I have added a callback to `getElement` - because it is much easier to type everything else.

Also I have added ItemMap - const

This is my solution:

```js
import React from "react"

/**
 * This is our data modelling
 * 
 * The goal here is to create a base model (called "Item") that can be extended with additional
 * data but must implement the basic Item fields (which the property "type").
 * We also wanted to have a map of the types that we have to their models. The idea for this was 
 * to make it work for us to map types of models to their specific variants
 */

// Here we have a couple of base types
type ItemType = "t1" | "t2" | "t3"

// We have a base model "item" that has a field "type" which is of ItemType
interface Item<T extends ItemType> {
    type: T;
}

// This defines a "Record<>" that maps every ItemType as a key to an Item of that type as a value
export type RecordOfItems = { [K in ItemType]: Item<K> };

// This helper lets us extend the basic RecordOfItems in a typesafe way:
// With this we can extend the RecordOfItems and make sure each key is still an
// ItemType and the value is an extension of the according Item.
// You cannot add other keys and you cannot use other values.
export type Items<T extends RecordOfItems> = T;

// This is the specific implementation of the RecordOfItems, we have t1-t3 as keys,
// each one is mapping to an item but extending it with their own props
type ItemMap = Items<{
    t1: { type: "t1"; foo: "foo" };
    t2: { type: "t2"; bar: "bar" };
    t3: { type: "t3"; baz: "baz" };
}>;

// If you want pass only Item as argument, we should also have a map
const ItemMap:ItemMap = {
    t1: { type: "t1", foo: "foo" },
    t2: { type: "t2", bar: "bar" },
    t3: { type: "t3", baz: "baz" },
}
// Now these were definitions of the possible data that we have, the
// data structure that we have is an array of items. The reason we create an
// ItemMap and now have an array of its values is the idea that we could map
// the ItemTypes which we can find in the `type` field to the according definition
// of the model when we read the data and need to look up which array item implements
// which model
const data: ItemMap[keyof ItemMap][] = [
    { type: "t1", foo: "foo" },
    { type: "t2", bar: "bar" },
    { type: "t3", baz: "baz" },
    { type: "t2", bar: "bar" },
    { type: "t1", foo: "foo" },
    { type: "t2", bar: "bar" },
    { type: "t2", bar: "bar" },
    { type: "t3", baz: "baz" },
]

type Data = typeof data

/**
 * This is our react implementation where we map our data to react components
 */

// We create another Record that maps the item types to React components
type ComponentMap = { [T in ItemType]: React.VFC<{ item: ItemMap[T] }> }


// This is the implementation of that
const componentMap: ComponentMap = {
    t1: ({ item }) => <p>{item.foo}</p>,
    t2: ({ item }) => <p>{item.bar}</p>,
    t3: ({ item }) => <p>{item.baz}</p>,
}

function foo<T extends ItemType>(item: Item<T>, callback: (comp: ComponentMap[T], props: ItemMap[T]) => JSX.Element): JSX.Element {
    const comp = componentMap[item.type];
    return callback(comp, ItemMap[item.type])
}

const Comp = foo({ type: 't1' }, (Comp, props) => <Comp item={props} />) // ok
const Comp2 = foo({ type: 't1' }, (Comp, props) => <Comp item={{ type: "t1", bar: "foow" }} /> //error
```