# Typescript: Generic Component Discriminating Between Different Input Props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an enum with two members,

```
enum Step {
  ONE = "StepOne",
  TWO = "StepTwo"
}
```

each of which are assigned to a property, `step` in a discriminating union

```
type Props =
  | { type: Step.TWO; headline: string }
  | { type: Step.ONE; headline: string[] };
```

There is a generic component that takes props of either shape in the union and returns a matching component from a "componentMap", object

```
const Component = <T extends Step>(props: Extract<Props, { step: T }>) => {
  const compMap = { StepOne, StepTwo };

  // This works but I don't want to need to cast Comp 
  // const Comp = compMap[props.type] as React.ComponentType<any>;

  const Comp = compMap[props.step];

  return <Comp {...props} />;
};
```

If I cast `compMap[props.step]` as `React.ComponentType<any>` (or as `React.FunctionComponent<any>` etc) I don't have a type error, but I'd like to not need to do this.

The specific error I get when not casting `compMap[props.step]` is:

```
Type '{ step: T; } & { step: Step.TWO; headline: string; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes'
```

So theres a mismatch happening somewhere...

Is there a way to correctly type this `Component` function so that it can infer the appropriate component it is meant to return?

[Here is a codesandbox with an example of the implementation for context](https://codesandbox.io/s/generic-component-issue-lvlj8?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: can import * as compMap from './componets', helps you to prevent casting, can't it.

Comment: @Spencer Pope I'd willing to bet that this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65201089/mapping-an-array-of-data-to-specific-react-components-based-on-a-type-field-in-t answer might help you

Comment: @captain-yossarian that looks good, thanks! It seems like it wouldn't work without the `callback` though right? I'm thinking that jcalz's answer that it's not possible the way I had wanted to write it is correct.

Comment: @Spencer Pope, yes, callback helps to infer types. jcalz answer is good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why you've chosen to make the *call signature* of `Component` generic; the input is of type `Props` and the output is of type `JSX.Element`.  Since the `T` parameter appears only once, there's no useful distinction from the caller's side between `<T extends Step>(props: Extract<Props, { step: T }>) => ...` and `(props: Props) => ...`.

You might hope that the *implementation* of `Component` would find the extra type information useful, but unfortunately it does not.  Nothing stops `T` from being the full union `Step`, and therefore `props` could be of type `Extract<Props, {step: Step}>`, i.e, just `Props`.  So `T` is not being helpful in the implementation either.  (See [microsoft/TypeScript#24085](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24085) and [microsoft/TypeScript#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808) for open feature requests related to narrowability of generic type parameters.)

Therefore, I'll switch to a non-generic function signature `(props: Props) => JSX.Element` from here on out.

---

I think the only way you will be able avoid a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) is by explicitly walking the compiler through the different possible `Props` cases.  This will allow [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) to take place:

```
const Component = (props: Props) => {
    return props.step === Step.ONE ? <StepOne {...props} /> : <StepTwo {...props} />;
};
```

That is, unfortunately, redundant.  It certainly doesn't scale if you've got `StepNinetySeven`.

---

It would be nice if the compiler could just understand that `compMap[props.step]` will always be able to accept `props`; but this would require support for what I've been calling *correlated types*, and there isn't any such support now.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) for a feature request around this.  Without being able to keep track of correlations between different union-typed values, the compiler only sees that `compMap[props.step]` is of type `StepOne | StepTwo` while `props` is of type `{ type: Step.TWO; headline: string } | { type: Step.ONE; headline: string[] }`.  The compiler treats these as uncorrelated or independent; for all it understands, `compMap[props.step]` might be `StepOne` while `props` is of type `{type: Step.TWO; headline: string }`.  So you get an error.

If you don't want redundant code, you currently have no choice but to use a type assertion to tell the compiler not to fret about the "wrong" pairings of `compMap[props.step]` and `props`.  This is giving up some type safety (the compiler no longer will catch certain errors).  You can do this with `any`, as you've done, which is the easiest.  More complicated is to take a union-of-functions and narrow it to a single function that accepts a union-of-its-parameters:

```
type UnifyFunctions<F extends (...args: any) => any> =
    (...x: Parameters<F>) => ReturnType<F>;

const Component = (props: Props) => {
    const compMap = { StepOne, StepTwo };
    const Comp = compMap[props.step] as 
      UnifyFunctions<typeof compMap[keyof typeof compMap]>;
    return <Comp {...props} />;
}
```

That pretends `Comp` will be happy with either of the two types of `props`, and thus `{...props}` is accepted; it's less unsafe than `any`, at least.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.3#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMowoxJwC+cAZlBCHAERSoYsDcAsAFD8kAO3zMySMLn5wZcAPIA5AKJwAvK3Fg5QpC0zTZAFQDqctRsphDAdwgt+1fvxgBPMFQAKjMITUGZAD64cISWAFxwmgB0JnJccAAWqAAmADbAOhGhUBkA5jT+cEF4oRIR0YpK8UkoaRlIWTA5QrkA2gC6NLwCfK7ucACyKBleED7meK0ecBmRlu0RSgAeTegwADyjPtgl4XDT1AB8XU58aBBCoXMS2lTqABR4NXU6NBFDI96ErRXK7QCUamOOEK7Bg+CgQjg90Ksjg60OsLhshwz3SOiiIBQYHu92AlBA2GAgNUxxhfGRlOR6wSACY4ABrJAuVQ4YBHNkE6jrAD0dMRFKpcP+-0cgspvIFwu61G6-HOl3gmhsEHMj0SKXRVGo72GQi232isQBQKk4rgYIhUJpAEZDqjNfVuXy7TK5WcLlcAMJMSA6IQwOQ5fLqdaGOBIFbCZK+TSHe5gL6LFZQNabL47EJ7cNHEnAwoKq7ncBDSTqPCaW7YZW2E7mwvwH3gczFsCl1qJsaEKKlMDtbpwy2Q+FNyQ4KITzs+Wg8w5u04NuCji7CeAPKeECIGvNmwdIcHDjc9yxqVTqX4qAD88Mrr3Hk6+M+OEXWNdV96iG6f856fSoAFUhGAOgXAAMXwIQMGAT11lAiMoyEGNoQnKIUCgXJNzgFAhBcHdsJcY5VEKe4UKWLc0JQEB9yQKBCFgw4d2QA8hEMNwkHo91F2Xf0YHpdck32L4dxBetPXgVtSwma4tB0atLBVOs4S430W19dsj17ToUF8QDgLAiCoJgv8IDoOAJOxVomRcEy4GM0zzL7KVZCHa1R1wFCvzgWcZX4IA)